# How to use DevExpress report designer and report viewer in Angular 10

Tags: c#, angular, report, devexpress, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using Angular 10 for front-end and .net core webAPI with repository pattern for back-end. I'm trying to use DevExpress(v20.1) reports. But I couldn't figure it out how to make it. I'm searcing it for a week but no result. [This](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/119431/web-reporting/javascript-reporting/angular/report-designer/quick-start/report-designer-integration-in-angular) page and [this](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/400196/web-reporting/javascript-reporting/server-side-configuration/report-designer/report-designer-server-side-configuration-asp-net-core) page explains it. but I couldn't figure out how to configure this part of code;

```
public class ReportDesignerController : Controller {
//...
 public ActionResult GetReportDesignerModel(string reportUrl) {
     string modelJsonScript =
         new ReportDesignerClientSideModelGenerator(HttpContext.RequestServices)
         .GetJsonModelScript(
             reportUrl,                 
             GetAvailableDataSources(), //this metod implemented 
             "DXXRD",   
             "DXXRDV",
             "DXXQB"      
         );
     return Content(modelJsonScript, "application/json");
 }
```

}

can anyone tell me how to configure  "DXXRD","DXXRDV","DXXRDV" correctly. I'm not using mvc so when I replace code with this;

```
new ReportDesignerClientSideModelGenerator()
         .GetJsonModelScript(
             reportUrl,                 
             GetAvailableDataSources(), 
             "ReportDesigner/Invoke",    
             "WebDocumentViewer/Invoke", 
             "QueryBuilder/Invoke"       .
         );
```

I have to use MVC to be able to call these controllers and views. But I'm not using mvc. At the point where I am now, I started to think that I wouldn't be able to achieve this without MVC. So;

- Is it possible to use DevExpress Reporting in projects like my project?
- If yes how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DevExpress Reporting components uses ASP.NET MVC Core controllers to process requests from the [Report Designer](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/400249/web-reporting/asp-net-core-reporting/end-user-report-designer), [Document Viewer](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/400248/web-reporting/asp-net-core-reporting/document-viewer), and [Query Builder](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/117591/web-reporting/gui/interface-elements/query-builder) using predefined routes:

- [WebDocumentViewerController](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.AspNetCore.Reporting.WebDocumentViewer.WebDocumentViewerController)
- [ReportDesignerController](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.AspNetCore.Reporting.ReportDesigner.ReportDesignerController)
- [QueryBuilderController](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.AspNetCore.Reporting.QueryBuilder.QueryBuilderController)

So it's mandatory to register the MVC middleware and ASP.NET Core MVC reporting controllers in your app. You can proceed by adding the following code at application startup:

```cs
    using DevExpress.AspNetCore;
    using DevExpress.AspNetCore.Reporting;
    //...
    
    public class Startup {
    //...
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
         // Register reporting services in an application's dependency injection container.
          services.AddDevExpressControls();
          // Use the AddMvcCore (or AddMvc) method to add MVC services.
           services.AddMvcCore(); 
     }
    
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
           // ...
           app.UseStaticFiles();
           // Initialize reporting services.
           app.UseDevExpressControls();
            // ...
      }
    }
```

You can find more information in documentation:

- [Document Viewer Server-Side Application (ASP.NET Core)](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/400197/web-reporting/javascript-reporting/server-side-configuration/document-viewer/document-viewer-server-side-configuration-asp-net-core)
- [Report Designer Server-Side Configuration (ASP.NET Core)](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/400196/web-reporting/javascript-reporting/server-side-configuration/report-designer/report-designer-server-side-configuration-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

[devexpress] have very bad documentation, I hope you will don't need that, else going to krazy :)

Dear Devexpress when we developers talk about documentation we mean similar to Doc in the link

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/

Please don't joke with developers